# Random Number Gen as function

Tags: c++, function, random

The goal of this program is to have a random number generator that I can use in the main through a function. Then the values from the random number generator will trigger an action. This has if statements checking the values from the generator. The problem I am having is both strings, "Numbers 1 - 5" and "Numbers 6 - 10" appear instead of the if statements triggering only what is expected from them which would make only one of the strings appear.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

void main()
{
    void RanNum1to10();
    int RanNum;
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    if (x == 2)
    {
        std::cout << "X = 2" << std::endl << std::endl;
        RanNum1to10();
        if (RanNum = 1||2||3||4||5)
        {
            std::cout << "Number 1 - 5" << std::endl;
        }
        if (RanNum = 6||7||8||9||10)
        {
            std::cout << "Number 6 - 10" << std::endl;
        }
    }
system("pause");
}

void RanNum1to10()
{
    (time(0));
    int RanNum;
    int x = 1+(rand() % 9 + 1);
    switch(x)
    {
        case 1:
            RanNum = 1;
        case 2:
            RanNum = 2;
        case 3:
            RanNum = 3;
        case 4:
            RanNum = 4;
        case 5:
            RanNum = 5;
        case 6:
            RanNum = 6;
        case 7:
            RanNum = 7;
        case 8:
            RanNum = 8;
        case 9:
            RanNum = 9;
        default:
            RanNum = 10;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You seriously need to get a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn the basics again.

Comment: Don't edit the question to make the code correct after it has been answered. That'll confuse later readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
    if ( (RanNum == 1) ||
         (RanNum == 2) ||
         (RanNum == 3) ||
         (RanNum == 4) ||
         (RanNum == 5) )
```

instead of

```
    if (RanNum = 1||2||3||4||5)
```

Similarly for the other `if` statement.

That's one problem.

The other problem is that you have the line:

```
int RanNum;
```

in `main` but you have not assigned any value to it.

You have assigned values to a local variable of the same name in `RanNum1to10` but that won't change the value of `RanNum` in `main`.

You can address that problem by changing the return vaule of `RanNum1to10` to `int`, and returning the random number from it, and assigning the return value of `RanNum1to10` to `RanNum`.

Change the line

```
void RanNum1to10();
```

to

```
int RanNum1to10();
```

Change the line

```
    RanNum1to10();
```

to

```
    RanNum = RanNum1to10();
```

Change the implementation of `RanNum1to10` to:

```
int RanNum1to10()
{
   return (rand() % 10 + 1);
}
```

**Update, in response to comment by OP**

Due to operator precedence, the expression `if (x = 2||3||4)` is equivalent to `if ( x = (2 || 3 || 4) )`, which is equivalent to `x = 1; if ( x )`. As you can see, the conditional of such an `if` statement always evaluates to true.

Comment: @Laina that's just the way expressions work in C and C++. If you look up the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) you'll see your expression is equivalent to `x = (2||3||4)`, and `2||3||4` evaluates to `1`. The result of `x = 1` is `1` or `true`.

Comment: Re your update: `=` has a lower precedence than `||` while `==` has a higher precedence. Your statement is *almost* correct.

Comment: regardless of operator precedence, `RanNum = (1||2||3||4||5)` or `(RanNum = 1)||2||3||4||5` is still always true because 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 are all "true" expressions and their arithmetic or is true too

Answer (score 0):

First problem: `if (x = 2)` should be `if (x == 2)`. Otherwise you're just testing the result of an assignment, which is equal to the number being assigned. The compiler should have generated a warning for this.

Second problem: to test against multiple values, you can't just `or` the values together with `||`. The result of such an expression will be true or false, equating to 1 or 0. You need to expand out each comparison:

```
if (RanNum == 1 || RanNum == 2 || RanNum == 3 || RanNum == 4 || RanNum == 5)
```

Of course in this particular case you can simplify the condition:

```
if (RanNum >= 1 && RanNum <= 5)
```

Comment: Thats why! Was wondering why if statements cant be if (RanNum = 1||2). Thank you, it helps a lot.